# Getting Wrong output in bubble sorting

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, bubble-sort

I am getting the wrong output for any value i entered, for example if i have entered 5,4,3,2,1 the output is 1,1,1,1,1... I have used the bubble sort algorithm in the function bubblesort... and passed the array A to the function but output consist of only the last value i entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
void bubblesort(int A[]);
int main(void)
{
  int A[SIZE]={0};
  int i;
  puts("Enter value to store it in integer");
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
  }
  puts("");
  bubblesort(A);
}

void bubblesort(int A[])
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
      if(A[j]>A[j+1])
      {
        int temp;
        temp=A[j+1];
        A[j]=A[j+1];
        A[j]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
    printf("%d ",A[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `A[j]=A[j+1];` should be `A[j+1]=A[j];`

Comment: swap is done as so
`temp = A[j];
A[j] = A[j + 1];
A[j+1] = temp;`

Comment: To free the bubble sort from relying in a fixed `#define`, consider passing the size of array to be sorted (i.e. `void bubblesort (int *a, size_t n)`) and also remove all output routines from the function and place those back in the caller (i.e. `main()`). **Note:** your loop declarations will be (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < (int)n; i++)` ) with the cast necessary to avoid comparing signed and unsigned values. (`n` should be `size_t` (unsigned) because it will never be negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One logical error:

Swapping

```
         temp=A[j+1];  // stores A[j+1] in temp
         A[j]=A[j+1];  // stores A[j+1] in A[j] - the value in A[j] is lost
         A[j]=temp;    // stores temp in A[j]
```

The proper way is :

```
         temp=A[j+1];   // stores A[j+1] in temp
         A[j+1]=A[j];   // stores A[j] in A[j+1] 
         A[j]=temp;     // stores temp in A[j]
```

Two suggestions:

Move this:  `int temp;` out of the `for loop`.

Change this:

```
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
```

to:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're close, but I suspect your problem is here:

```
int temp;
temp=A[j+1];
A[j]=A[j+1];
A[j]=temp;
```

I believe that you want to set `temp=A[j]` so that you can later set `A[j+1] = temp` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code for Bubble Sort

```
   #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[100], n, c, d, swap;

  printf("Enter Total Terms\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter %d Elements\n", n);

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
//bubble sort logic 
  for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
  {
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
      if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /*  use < For decreasing order */
      {
        swap       = array[d];
        array[d]   = array[d+1];
        array[d+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("ascending order:\n");

  for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
     printf("%d\n", array[c]);

  return 0;
}
```